# Lightroom Camera Lens Motor Noise Reduction

Tags: lightroom, hd-video

Possibly a quick question, but I thought I heard LR3 was supposed to have a feature for reducing camera motor noise.  Was I dreaming?  If not, what else can I use to reduce the all of that focusing noise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really see how Lightroom, which is software for a computer designed to edit photos, could have anything to do with the physical motor noise of a lens. Lens noise is part of the construction of the lens (and possibly camera body), and not something a piece of third-party software can change. If your lens is particularly noisy...you might want to look into getting a better lens...perhaps something with a silent ultrasonic type motor.

Comment: Lens motors can produce interference which results in image noise, which might be what the questioner is referring to.

Comment: I'd guess this question would better be asked at a video-forum. Nevertheless I also occasionally did 'abuse' my cameras for videos in the past and added my experiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for tools to reduce focusing noise (sound) in your videos: sometimes, when the noise becomes too unnerving I demux (separate video and audio) the video and use Audacity (free) for reworking the sound.

Audacity is not the best tool and you need a "silent" part to properly denoise but it helps a bit. The plus is, that if you already demuxed the video, you can convert to mp3 or other better compressed sound-formats.

Other than that: (Windows-Tools) VirtualDub (free) is fine for basic video-editing and converting. Scriptable too. If it cannot read the input (H264 (lite)), look at AviSynth+ffshowtryouts (free; with AviSynth installed you create a file that serves as streaming file container for the video to be opened with VirtualDub, ffdshow does decode silently).

That said, video editing takes time, is tedious and ... if you are really into it, buy a professional tool: see Adobe Premiere for example.

Answer (score 10):

Not camera **motor** noise -- camera *picture noise*. That is, there's a feature in Lightroom 3 to make your photos less "grainy", which can happen under low-light conditions (higher ISO settings) or when using cameras with small sensors. If you are looking for audio noise reduction on recorded video, you're going to need to look at video editing software (and perhaps even stripping out the soundtrack and processing the audio separately).

Answer (score 1):

Some non-ultrasonic lens focus motors can produce RF interference when using servo mode which can produce image noise. This is different in character to photon/dark current noise (it tends to occur in distinct bands as has a regular frequency) and thus requires different tools for removal. I don't think LightRoom has any option to specifically remove this sort of image noise however.